# What's the difference between a[(input + 1):length(a)] and a[input + 1:length(a)]

Tags: r

I was trying to splice a vector in R when I observed a very strange thing.

When I enter-

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
input <- 1
a[input + 1: length(a)]
```

The output is

```
[1]  2  3  4 NA
```

But when I enter-

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
input <- 1
a[(input + 1): length(a)]
```

The output is

```
[1]  2  3  4
```

Why is this strange behavior observed?

Comment: What is the precedence between `+` and `:`?

Comment: See [operator precedence in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)

Comment: got it.. thanks a lot!